# Problems with raspberry pi and python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, interrupt, rfid

I have 2 questions.

1º - I have a raspberry pi that has connected to itself a ultrasonic sensor, a rfid reader and a pi camera. The problem I'm facing is that after like 10 reads of the rfid reader, it starts reading really slow ( takes probably 10 seconds to read 1 card ) or even stops reading.

2º - I would like to aplly interrupts in the devices mentioned above, but I dont know how to do it even though I have been searching a lot about this.

Does anybody knows why is this happening?

Comment: If you don't get a useful answer here, consider reposting this to the Raspberry PI StackExchange.

Comment: Also, what does "apply interrupts" in this context mean?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! I want the code for this devices to run in the "background" while other code is being executed

Comment: Regarding your first question, you will have to provide your code showing how you read data from the RFID reader. Otherwise, it is impossible to tell whether this is a hardware or software issue. Regarding your second question, I would recommend you use [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Getting-Started). It spins up a separate and detachable shell. You run scripts in it, detach it from the terminal, and your code is running "in the background".

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll try out tmux, but one thing I didn't mention is that i'm building an eletron app with python which uses npm python shell to run the python code you thing the problem might be because of this?